# Modificar el valor de los elementos en jQuery: val(), text() o html() ... ¿cuál es la diferencia?

Tags: jquery

Estaba escribiendo código jQuery para una respuesta aquí.

El código lee un archivo JSON con diferentes claves y de forma dinámica asigna cada valor a los inputs de un formulario usando `val()`. Algo así:

```
                        $.each(value, function(key, value){
                            $('#'+key).val(value);
                        });
```

El problema es que también tengo en el DOM un `<div id="error"></div>` para mostrar mensajes de error, cuando el JSON venga con una clave llamada `error`... pero mi bucle anterior no me sirve, ya que **no puedo usar `val()` en caso de que sea un `div`**.

Tuve entonces que recurrir a `text` y modificar mi código de esta forma:

```
                    /*Mostramos posibles  errores*/
                    if(value.hasOwnProperty('error')){
                        $('#error').text(value["error"]);
                    }else{
                        $.each(value, function(key, value){
                            $('#'+key).val(value);
                        });
                    }
```

Me surgió entonces la pregunta sobre la diferencia entre esos métodos que existen en jQuery para asignar valores a los elementos: **`val()`, `text()` y `html()`**.

¿Por qué por ejemplo no puedo usar `val()` para mostrar mis mensajes en el `div`? ¿Cuál es el motivo para que funcionen distintamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) se usa para leer/definir el valor de un campo (`input`, `select`, `textarea`). Como lo que se está cambiando sería el atributo `value` del elemento, no funcionará en otros elementos como `div` que no tienen atributo `value`.

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) se usa para leer/definir el texto contenido en un elemento (sea el que sea) y sus descendientes. Es decir, devolverá el texto sin etiquetas HTML. Y si se usa para asignar un valor, las etiquetas se mostrarán como texto (p.e. `<` se convertirá en `&lt;`).

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) se usa para leer/definir el código HTML contenido en un elemento (sea el que sea) y sus descendientes. Con esto no sólo se devolverá el texto sino también las etiquetas HTML.

---

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código:

```
<div id="midiv">
  Hola 
  <span>Caracola</span>
</div>
```

Si se hace `$("#midiv").val()` se obtendrá una cadena vacía (porque como es un `div` no tiene un valor). Si se hace `$("#midiv").text()` el resultado será `Hola Caracola` (sólo el texto sin etiquetas). Y si se hace `$("#midiv").html()` el resultado será `Hola <span>Caracola</span>`.

Comment: Pensé lo que tú dices sobre `text`, pero no me funciona en los `input`. Yo intenté esto en mi bucle: `$('#'+key).text(value);` y no me funcionó. La idea era no tener que recurrir al `if` para asignar valores al `div` en el caso de errores, pero no logré encontrar un método que asigne valores indistintamente a los `inputs` o a los `div`.

Comment: `.text()` no va a funcionar en un `input`, porque son etiquetas simples que no tienen texto/código dentro. ¿Entonces lo que quieres es usar algo que funcione independientemente de la etiqueta que sea sin el `if`?

Comment: Correcto, un método que sirva para cambiar los valores sea de los `input`, sea de los `div`. De ese modo, recorrería el JSON sin tener que recurrir al `if`.

Comment: Que yo sepa no hay ningún método (aunque puede haber cambiado). Una posibilidad sería tener el valor que quieres poner en una variable y hacer `.val()` y `.text()` encadenados. (algo como `.val(nuevoValor).text(nuevoValor)`). Hacer `val` en un elemento que no tiene valor, no afectaría en nada; y hacer `text` en un `input` tampoco afectaría (pero podría dar problemas con un `select`).

Comment: En ese caso sería mejor el `if`.